# socket identifier equals -1

Tags: c++, network-programming, protocol-buffers

Somehow, someway the socket is -1. It shouldn't be because my client program connects and send information but is stopped by SIGPIPE signal. When I debug the server I see that accept returns -1. I have got no idea why. If you no, answer please.

client.cpp

```
using namespace std;
using namespace msg;
using namespace dataExchange;

int main() {
  Connection con("127.0.0.1", 123456);
  Annoucement ann;
  ann.set_typ(Annoucement::AKCJA);
  con.send(ann);
}
```

server.cpp

```
using namespace std;
using namespace msg;
using namespace dataExchange;

int main() {
  Server server(123456);
  while(1) {
    Connection con = server.accept();
    Annoucement ann = con.receive();
    cout << ann.typ() << endl;
  }
}
```

connect.cpp

```
using namespace msg;
using namespace google::protobuf;
using namespace google::protobuf::io;

namespace dataExchange {

  class SocketMaintenance {
  protected:
    sockaddr_in addr;
    int s;
  public:
    SocketMaintenance(const unsigned int port) {
      memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
      addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      addr.sin_port = htons(port);
      s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    }
    SocketMaintenance(const sockaddr_in Addr, const int Socket) {
      addr = Addr;
      s = Socket;
    }
    SocketMaintenance(const SocketMaintenance& source) {
      addr = source.addr;
      s = source.s;
    }
    ~SocketMaintenance() {
      close(s);
    }
    void write(const char* buffer, const int n) {
      ::write(s, buffer, n);
    }
  };

  class Connection : public SocketMaintenance {
    FileOutputStream* raw_output;
    FileInputStream* raw_input;
    char buffer[1024];
  public:
    Connection(const char* IP, const unsigned int port) : SocketMaintenance(port) {
      if(inet_pton(AF_INET, IP, &addr.sin_addr)<=0) {
    throw WrongAddress();
      }
      if(connect(s, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))<0) {
    throw ConnectFailed();
      }
      raw_output = new FileOutputStream(s);
      raw_input = new FileInputStream(s);
    }
    Connection(const SocketMaintenance& source) : SocketMaintenance(source) {}
    ~Connection() {
      delete raw_output;
    }
    void send(const Message& msg) throw(EmptyMessage)  {
      CodedOutputStream* coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);
      int n = msg.ByteSize();
      if(n<=0) throw EmptyMessage();
      coded_output->WriteVarint32(n);
      delete coded_output;
      raw_output->Flush();
      msg.SerializeToArray(buffer, n);
      SocketMaintenance::write(buffer, n);
    }
    Annoucement receive() throw() {
      CodedInputStream* coded_input = new CodedInputStream(raw_input);
      google::protobuf::uint32 n;
      coded_input->ReadVarint32(&n);
      char *b;
      int m;
      coded_input->GetDirectBufferPointer((const void**)&b, &m);
      Annoucement ann;
      ann.ParseFromArray(b, n);
      return ann;
    }

  };

  class Server : public SocketMaintenance {
  public:
    Server(const unsigned int port) : SocketMaintenance(port) {
      addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
      if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))<0) {
    throw BindFailed();
      }
      if(listen(s, 5)<0) {
    throw ListenFailed();
      }
    }
    Connection accept() throw() {
      sockaddr_in client;
      socklen_t client_len;
      int client_socket = ::accept(s, (sockaddr*)&client, &client_len);
      return Connection(SocketMaintenance(client, client_socket));
    }
  };

}
```

I have tested this code before I rearranged it into classes. Then it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One glaring issue I see is that your port is invalid. `sockaddr_in::sin_port` is a `uint16_t`, whose largest value can possibly be 65536. Best case, you're truncating your port on the call to `htons`, which should result in 57920.

In regards to why the accept is failing, `-1` indicates an error occured, and you should check the value of `errno` to see why.

From `man 2 accept`:

> RETURN VALUE
>          On success, accept() returns a non-negative integer that is a
>   descriptor for the accepted socket. 
>   On error, -1 is returned, and errno
>          is set appropriately.

Comment: errno is equal 22 - invalid argument. Socket argument was equal 5. Don't know what is wrong :/

Comment: socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client); that is ok. Thx for info. I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, somewhere in there you are passing a socket class object by value and its destructor is closing the socket prematurely. I couldn't be bothered wading through the code to find out if that is the case, but some observations:

- don't allocate things with new unless you absolutely have to
- don't implement copy constructors if all they do is what the default copy constructor should do
- DO prevent copying of socket objects by declaring copy constructors and assignment operators as private and then not implementing them
- don't "rearrange" things into classes - either start out writing classes from the get go, or just write procedural code

Comment: I suppose it has nothing to do because when I comment the close(s) in destructor problem remains.